# has iron-router a group function like flow-router

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router, flow-router

Hey Ladys and Gentlenerds! ;-)

is there a way to handle my URLs with a prefix or group or something like that?

```
cooldomain.com/admin
cooldomain.com/admin/posts
cooldomain.com/admin/comments
cooldomain.com/admin/something
```

[Flow-Router Groups](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/introduction-to-flow-router/#group-routes)

i don't want to remove iron-router... i use iron-cli and iron-controller too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use route parameters and perform an action based on which admin sub page you navigate to.

```
// cooldomain.com/admin/posts
Router.route('/admin/:page', function () {
  var params = this.params; // { page: "posts" }
  var page = params.page; // "posts"
  // Do something based on page value
});
```